# In Firefox on Ubuntu 16.04, is there a way to conveniently be able to right-click on bookmarks to access the context menu?

Tags: 16.04, unity, firefox, gui, bookmarks

The right-click doesn't work in the Linux window menu.
By "conveniently" I mean:

- without opening a new window with bookmarks
- without having the Bookmarks Toolbar permanently occupy much space on the screen. I tried squeezing it but sooner or later Firefox always makes it large again.

Comment: You could quickly show and hide the bookmarks sidebar with Ctrl+B.

Comment: Thanks, it seems like the Firefox Sidebar is indeed a good solution and even has some more advantages over the Bookmarks Toolbar rather than just not permanently occupying much space. I will test it. If you post your comment as an answer, I will probably accept it as a solution.

Comment: So you don't want the bookmarks toolbar to show but you want to right click on bookmarks? I don't understand. My bookmarks toolbar shows, I can right click on a bookmark and get the exact context menu as I would get if I right clicked a bookmark from the bookmark sidebar.

This is on ubuntu 19.04 on the default gnome session but it seems that the latest firefox which i am running is also in 16.04.

Comment: @Andrew this is the solution I've been using so far and what I don't like in it is that then the toolbar permanently occupies quite a lot of space on the screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I personally find the sidebars Firefox offers (Bookmarks or History) to be quite user friendly and allow you to browse your links as a tree/list and filter them with a basic quick search bar.

They can also be shown and hidden again easily with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> respectively, or from the *View* → *Sidebar* menu.

Right-clicking entries to get a full context menu is supported in there too, just like in the Library window.